# null reference to a Singleton object

Tags: android, singleton

I am trying to create a global variable where it can be accessed from any any where including Activity, Fragment and other custom classes.

```
public class Global extends Application {
private static Global sInstance;
private String mSharedInfoFileName; //can be any custom object

public static Global getInstance() { return sInstance; }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() { mSharedInfoFileName = "globalInfo"; }

public String getFileName() { return mSharedInfoFileName; }

private Global() { }
```

}

and try to use it like this

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
            String s = Global.getInstance().getFileName();

            }
```

even after declaring it in class scope still gave same error

```
    private static Global mGlobal = Global.getInstance();
```

which give me Attempt to invoice... .Global.getFileName()' on a null object reference. What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this method to static :

```
public static String getFileName() {
   return mSharedInfoFileName; 
}
```

and call it like below:

```
Global.getFileName();
```

The mSharedInfoFileName variable has to be static too :

```
private static String mSharedInfoFileName;
```